# What happens inside a conducting wire if it is placed in an electric field?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, voltage, conductors

what happens when you place a long Finite conducting wire in an Electric Field , does current flow  through it ? Is Potential Same all over the wire ?

i just got these questions in my mind as i was watching a lecture...i am unable to answer these...any useful explanation is appreciated

Comment: By "long" you mean infinite? Do you understand what happens if the conductor is "short"?

Comment: @nasu No, I mean Long Finite Wire

Comment: https://youtu.be/oI_X2cMHNe0 12:50 short answer, an initial current is generated, but quickly goes to zero

Answer (score 4):

If the field is static, the conductor will be equipotential in the equilibrium state. If you bring the conductor in the field from a region with no field or with a different value of the field there will be some motion of charge (so, a current) until the equilibrium is reached. The same happens when you turn on the field. A very short lived motion (redistribution) of the free charges until all points of the conductor have the same potential. There is nothing special about a wire. Same happens for any shape of the conductor.

Comment: Good answer +1. You might also mention that the time it takes to reach equilibrium depends on the size of the conductor. So for a very long conductor it could take a long time. This is essentially what makes an antenna work best at a certain frequency

Comment: @nasu Does the presence of the wire effect the electric vector field?

Comment: What electric field? Produced by what?